# what would setting W as the way to default exit out of other tools cause in terms of conflict?

Tags: workflow

say you set W to not cycle through and only select the plain selector. 
I find myself always having to mouse to the selector icon to exit out of other tools. 
example when i use poly build. to exit i hit select icon. 
i suppose I could set Select tool to my quick favorites. press q and then selector.

i'd like W as my exit and like crtl+w to cycle box circl lasso sel.

is this a bad idea? (for modeling purposes)

Answer (score 0):

What do you want?

If you want to discuss a modelling process - it is off-topic because it is to broad. Question must be about specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Blenderartists.org is better place to discuss broad questions.

If you want to ask is it correct to edit keymap - Yes, it is correct. Feel free to edit keyboard shortcuts as you want.

If you want to suggest it as default - use devtalk.blender.org forum to create discussion about it.